# scroll in table with blazor

Tags: user-interface, blazor

I designed a table by html and css in blazor .
I need to have the following function:
when the onkeydown event is executed,if pressed down key , scroll the rows of the table .

this is my onkeydown method :

```
    public async void TableOnClick(KeyboardEventArgs arg)
    {
        int row = 0;
        var item = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Selected || x.EditeMode);
        if (arg.Code == "ArrowDown")
        {
            row = item.Row + 1;
        }
        else if (arg.Code == "ArrowUp")
        {
            row = item.Row - 1;
        }
        if (item != null && item.Selected)
        {

            SelectItem(row);
        }
        else if (item != null && item.Selected)
        {
            SelectItem(row);
        }

        try
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("GoTo", "a1", $"Row-{item.Row}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

```
function GoTo(parentid, id) {
    //alert(parentid + "|" + id);
    //alert($("#" + id).position().top);
    $("#" + parentid).delay(1).animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + id).position().top }, 800, 'swing');
}
```

Comment: What's happening that you are unhappy about?  It seems to me that the Default `item` vlaue is probably `null`, in which case you will probably throw an error in your `row = item.Row +1` or `-1` calculations if you press an arrow key before anything is selected or put in edit mode.  But maybe you can give more details about what problem you have?

Comment: When I display many records in the table, the scroll speed of the table is faster than my selected record. Therefore, the selected record is not shown

Comment: try adding a `await Task.Delay(1);` before/after your JsRuntime invoke.